# Need to pass email id in the request URL in Springs(RESTful webservice)

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I need to pass email id in the request URI :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/version2/auth/users/{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Example : 
http://localhost:8081/myServices/version2/auth/users/me@myMail.com

I am getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:234)

Can you please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do escaping and then attach the email id to your URL and invoke controller REST API. Once recieved unescape it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this method returns an object of some User class. Does your user class have the proper public getters and setters? Do you have the jackson libraries added?

Comment: Hi Loredana, Yes, i have the proper getter and setter methods for the userid. I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

Comment: Can you paste your User class please?

Comment: import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;                         public class UserDetails { @NotEmpty
 @JsonProperty("userId")
 private String userid;                                                                public String getUserid() {
  return userid;
 }

 public void setUserid(String userid) {
  this.userid = userid;
 }

Comment: Thanks. You should have @JsonProperty("userid") instead of "userId" to be the same as your class property.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the property to  @JsonProperty("userid"). But i am still getting the same exception

Comment: Other possible causes I can think of: missing the jackson-jaxrs dependency or missing jacksonMessageConverter in your configuration. Do you have other json mappings that work or is this the only one?

Comment: Actually now that I look at your example url, you have a dot in there which Spring is probably interpreting as an extension. Try writing the value attribute like this: value = "/version2/auth/users/{userid:.*}"

Comment: Hello Loredana, i tried with this /v2/auth/users/{userid:.*} but still i am getting the same exception

Comment: When you request this url, do you have the header Accept:application/json added to the request?

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I also tried with Accept:*/* . But did not work

Comment: This link: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/123963-spring-json-causes-problems-when-the-spring-framework-is-upgraded-from-3-0-2-to-3-2-0 suggests adding contentNegotiationManager to your spring configuration